# Google Maps API not retrieving all stores result

Tags: python, api, google-maps

I wrote up a quick script to fetch all stores (tried to do so anyway) provided a zipcode, it looks like this:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

API_KEY = "MYKEY"

google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)


query_result = google_places.nearby_search(location="94563", keyword="store", radius=50000)

if query_result.has_attributions:
    print query_result.html_attributions

for place in query_result.places:
    print place.name
```

These are the results that I get:

```
Apple Store
Stonestown Galleria
Lawrence Hall of Science
Fentons Creamery
Nordstrom
The North Face
Amoeba Music
Safeway
Rockridge Market Hall
City Beer Store
Best Buy
City Lights Booksellers & Publishers
Macy's
Barnes & Noble
Rainbow Grocery
Target
Urban Outfitters
The UPS Store
AT&T
Marshalls
```

But if we head over to maps.google.com we can query for the same stores and this is what we get:

[image: stores sample]

We notice that there are many stores in this result set that are not queried from the API. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When more than 20 results come up with a `nearby search`, a next_page_token is also returned by the API, and a separate call must be made to retrieve them [[Reference]](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests). I don't know whether the googleplaces package you're using is able to do that, but that is most likely the reason you're getting exactly 20 results; the rest are there, you just need to call the API again to get them.

My recommendation would be to ditch the package and instead deal with Google's API directly. Here is some helper code to get you started doing that. You will need to download and install [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) if you don't have it already.

```
import json
import urllib
import time
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
l = geolocator.geocode('94563') #enter the zip code you're interested in to get lat/long coords


longitude = l.longitude
latitude = l.latitude

resultslist = []
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+str(latitude)+','+str(longitude)+'&radius=50000&types=store&key=<put your key here>' #construct URL, make sure to add your key without the <>
count = 0
ps= json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
for i in ps['results']:
    #parse results here
    resultslist.append(i)
    count += 1
if ps['next_page_token']: 
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        npt = ps['next_page_token']

        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+str(latitude)+','+str(longitude)+'&radius=50000&types=store&key=<yourkey>&pagetoken='+str(npt)

        ps= json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

        for i in ps['results']:
            resultslist.append(i)
            #parse results here
            count += 1

        try:
            ps['next_page_token']
        except:
            break

print 'results returned:',count
```

Comment: So it seems like this solved my main issue, but one small concern, would changing the zipCdoe to its longitude and latitude change the results to not be restricted to a zip? @Ryan

Comment: That is correct: the results from the example above will be within a 50,000 meter radius of the lat/long location, which could extend beyond the boundaries of the zip code. You can easily filter for results that are only from a particular zip by reading the `reference` data that is returned and then passing it to a Place Details search which will give you zip code data: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Comment: tried filtering out the results and funny enough not a single one of the results were from stores from the zip that I wanted :| But this is getting me one step further in what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: You might try doing a Radar Search (see first reference). The limit there is 200 versus a limit of 60 for the Nearby Search. Also, reducing the radius size will probably help narrow down the results. Might also be worth taking a look at the lat/long that geopy is giving you for a zip and see if that is a good match for the region you're interested in.